# Right way to handle json data without looping in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

What is the right way to handle json data without looping? The data that comes in is a json array like this: `Object {idPri="1",idSec="2"}`

I'll be using jQuery's `$.ajax` to do this

```
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"testUserData.php",
  data:data,
  dataType:'json',
  success: function(userData) {
    $('.h2[data-id="'+idPri+'"]').find('span[data-sec="'+idSec+'"]').hide();
  }
}
```

I intend putting the `idPri` and `idSec` from the json array into the `idPri` and `idSec` inside the `success` function. What is the right way to do this? The size of that json array never changes, only the values change.

I presently do: `userData.idPrid` and `userData.idSec`

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now? I don't see the looping anywhere.

Comment: That's the correct way to extract properties from a Javascript object. What else do you think you need?

Comment: `userData.idPrid` is the correct way to read the `idProd` property from the returned data

Comment: thats not an array thats just a object

Comment: You say userData is an array, but the way your code looks it's actually a single object with two properties (idPri and idSec). You're asking how to do this without a loop, yet have the solution right there. I'm not sure I understand the problem/question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`idPri` is not a variable, it's a property of an object.  jQuery passes the object to your success handler, and you call that object `userData`.  To access it you can do `userData.idPri` or `userData["idPri"]`.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
     url:"testUserData.php",
    data:data,
dataType:'json',
success: function(userData){
    $('.h2[data-id="'+userData.idPri+'"]').find('span[data-sec="'+userData.idSec+'"]').hide();
},
```

Answer (score 1):

> I presently do: userData.idPrid and userData.idSec

Wouldn't that work, then?

```
success: function(userData){
    $('.h2[data-id="'+userData.idPri+'"]').find('span[data-sec="'+userData.idSec+'"]').hide();
}
```

`function(userData)` passes the result object to your callback function, not making its properties available...